# How do I combine multiple grep commands?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a command like this:

```
| grep -v @param | grep -v @return | grep -v @Test | grep -v @throws
```

And it's getting bigger. Is there a way to make this neater?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another option:

```
... | grep -v -e @param -e @return -e @Test -e @throws
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
... | grep -v "\(@param\|@return\|@Test\|@throws\)"
```

or you can use the -E flag to enable extended regular expressions, which will allow you to avoid escaping the parentheses and pipe characters:

```
... | grep -Ev '(@param|@return|@Test|@throws)'
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can place all your patterns in a file, one pattern per line, and use

```
... | grep -v -f matches.txt
```

Would make things easier if you use the patterns regularly